# Ionic 4 + HttpInterceptor + token

Tags: javascript, token, ionic4, angular-http-interceptors, cordova-nativestorage

I'm trying to authenticate all the API calls to the backend using an HttpInterceptor in an Ionic 4 project. The token is saved through NativeStorage. The problem occurs when I make the login call. Since there is not yet an available token, NativeStorage returns an error interrupting the chain: NativeStorageError {code: 2, source: "Native", exception: null}

httpConfig.interceptor.ts

```
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';

@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  loaderToShow: any;
  loadingPresent = false;
  debug = false;
  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    private storage: NativeStorage
  )
  { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      return from(this.storage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY))
        .pipe(
          switchMap(token => {
            if (token) {
                request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token.access_token) });
            }
            if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
              request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
            }

            this.showLoader();

            return next.handle(request).pipe(

              map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                  console.log('event--->>>', event);
                }
                this.hideLoader();
                return event;
              }),
              catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.hideLoader();
                return throwError(error);
              })
            );

          })
        );
  }

  showLoader() {
    console.log("show loader");
    this.loaderToShow = this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Cargando datos...'
    }).then((res) => {

      this.loadingPresent = true;
      res.present();

      res.onDidDismiss().then((dis) => {
        console.log('Loading dismissed!');
      });
    });
  }

  hideLoader() {
    if(this.loadingPresent) {
      this.loadingController.dismiss();
      this.loadingPresent = false;
    }
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  token:any;

  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: NativeStorage,
    private plt: Platform
  )
  {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkToken();
    });
  }

  login(login: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(environment.API_URL + 'auth/login',
      { login: login, password: password }
    ).pipe(
        map(token => {
          this.storage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token)
          .then(
            () => {
              this.authenticationState.next(true);
            },
            error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
          );
        }),
    );
  }

  logout() {
    return this.http.get(environment.API_URL + 'auth/logout')
    .pipe(
      tap(data => {
        return this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY).then(() => {
          this.authenticationState.next(false);
        });
      })
    )
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationState.value;
  }


  checkToken() {
    this.storage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY).then(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.authenticationState.next(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I try to login the first time, it returns the "token not found" error by NativeStorage from the interceptor
NativeStorageError {code: 2, source: "Native", exception: null}

Answer (score 0):

you try to access to `'TOKEN_KEY'` item when item doesn't exist.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   return from(this.storage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)) <-- //This causes error
```

or

```
checkToken() {
  this.storage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY).then(res => { <-- //This causes error
    if (res) {
       this.authenticationState.next(true);
    }
  });
}
```

you must initialize default value for `'TOKEN_KEY'` or add if else condition for controlling(checking) token

you can use `this.storage.keys` list for find your key

other error codes:

- NATIVE_WRITE_FAILED = 1
- **ITEM_NOT_FOUND = 2**
- NULL_REFERENCE = 3
- UNDEFINED_TYPE = 4
- JSON_ERROR = 5
- WRONG_PARAMETER = 6

Comment: Hi Onur, thanks for your answer. From what I understand, to maintain the structure like this, I have to check at startup if the "TOKEN_KEY" key exists in NativeStorage. If not, I have to create it empty. In case of logout, instead of deleting the key, I have to empty it. I was wondering if it is worth an approach like this or if I have to look for another way.

Comment: @elektropier don’t need to look for another way, your way is the best way to do what you want. And you need to continue from that way. Only make sure your ‘TOKEN_KEY’ exists

Answer (score 0):

the get function from ionic storage return the value as object { value : "token value "}

so access value property from storage result like this

```
request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
                         token.value) });
```